# print array values left and right (by turns )

Tags: php, html, css

I have array

```
 $mas = array("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","fff");
```

I want print this array so:

```
 aaa bbb
 ccc ddd
 fff
```

I do not wondered, how to make html/css for this, please tell me

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
span.row {
  display:block;
}

span.margin {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

PHP:

```
$mas = array("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","fff");

echo '<span class="row">';

for($i = 0; $i < count($mas); $i++) {
  echo $i % 2 == 0 ? '</span><span class="row">';
  echo '<span class="margin">' . $mas[$i] . '</span>';
}

echo '</span>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print an array with two items per line, you can try the following:

```
<?php
$output = "<div>";
for($i = 0; $i < count($mas); $i++)
{
    if($i % 2 == 0)
        $output .= "<p>".$mas[$i]." ";
    else
        $output .= $mas[$i]."</p>";
}
echo $output."</div>";
```

Use CSS to style the `<p>` tags to your liking with regards to spacing.